# What happens with unarchived objects?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, crash, nskeyedarchiver

After I've unarchived an object with NSKeyedUnarchiver, I am able to use it like usual, but I am unable to re-archive it. When I try, it crashes.

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:unarchivedObject toFile:fileName];
```

I tried looking in the developer resources in apple but I haven't seen a thorough explination of proper usage of NSKeyedArchiver. Please Help.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000023
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:
iPhone Simulator 3.2 (193.8), iPhone OS 3.2 (iPad/7B367)

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x958a0ed7 objc_msgSend + 23
1   OGLGame                         0x0000c7e2 -[Sounds encodeWithCoder:] + 59 (Sounds.m:86)
2   Foundation                      0x0280d25b _encodeObject + 827
3   Foundation                      0x028243cc -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 284
4   Foundation                      0x0281a367 -[NSArray(NSArray) encodeWithCoder:] + 615
5   Foundation                      0x0280d25b _encodeObject + 827
6   OGLGame                         0x0000ebc2 -[Row encodeWithCoder:] + 244 (Row.m:153)
7   Foundation                      0x0280d25b _encodeObject + 827
8   Foundation                      0x028243cc -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 284
9   Foundation                      0x0281a367 -[NSArray(NSArray) encodeWithCoder:] + 615
10  Foundation                      0x0280d25b _encodeObject + 827
11  Foundation                      0x0285de10 +[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:] + 176
```

As far as I can tell, it might be my Sounds class. I'll check it over while you check this over.

Although, after research I found this:

```
replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:
```

Overridden by subclasses to substitute another object for itself during keyed archiving.

- (id)replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:(NSKeyedArchiver *)archiver

Parameters
archiver
A keyed archiver creating an archive.
Return Value
The object encode instead of the receiver (if different).

*Discussion
This method is called only if no replacement mapping for the object has been set up in the encoder (for example, due to a previous call of replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver: to that object).*

Comment: You need to post the contents of `-[Sounds encodeWithCoder:]`. Please try to think when posting what the other guys/ladies here would need to understand the bug. Be imaginative!

Comment: does every object conform the `NSCoding` protocol which you'd like to archive?

Answer (score 1):

A thread on the Apple dev forums seems to indicate that `replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:` is called on the objects you are attempting to encode. It sounds like one of the objects you are trying to encode inside `-[Sounds encodeWithCoder:]` has been freed from memory and `replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:` is being called it on causing a seg fault.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1079616